# Python - walk through a huge set of files but in a more efficient manner

Tags: python, os.walk

I have huge set of files that I want to traverse through using python. I am using os.walk(source) for the same and is working but since I have a huge set of files it is taking too much and memory resources since its getting the complete list all at once. How can I optimize this to use less resources and may be walk through one directory at a time or in some other efficient manner and still able to iterate the complete set of files. Thanks

```
for dir, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(START_FOLDER): 
    for name in dirnames: 
        #if PRIVATE_FOLDER not in name: 
            for keyword in FOLDER_WITH_KEYWORDS_DELETION_EXCEPTION_LIST: 
                if keyword in name.lower(): 
                    ignoreList.append(name)
```

Comment: `os.walk` already returns a generator, which is lazy. Are you turning it into a list or something? Because if not, it should not cause memory issues. (Also, post your code.)

Comment: I want to go through each of the file name and if contains certain keywords I want to add them to a list                              for dir, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(START_FOLDER):
        for name in dirnames:
            #if PRIVATE_FOLDER not in name:
                for keyword in FOLDER_WITH_KEYWORDS_DELETION_EXCEPTION_LIST:
                    if keyword in name.lower():
                        ignoreList.append(name)

Comment: Okay. Post your code that does that.

Comment: @senshin <code> for dir, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(START_FOLDER): 
    for name in dirnames: 
    #if PRIVATE_FOLDER not in name: 
        for keyword in FOLDER_WITH_KEYWORDS_DELETION_EXCEPTION_LIST: 
            if keyword in name.lower(): 
                ignoreList.append(name) </code>

Comment: Comments can't contain formatted code, you'd better edit your post and insert the snippet there.

Comment: How long does it take just to do the listing itself? As in, if you were to just run "for dir, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(START_FOLDER): pass", is it still unacceptably slow/memory intensive?

Comment: What is `len(FOLDER_WITH_KEYWORDS_DELETION_EXCEPTION_LIST)`? You can hoist the `name.lower()` out of the innermost loop, which can help if the keywords list is very large.

Comment: See [this link](http://www.olark.com/spw/2011/08/you-can-list-a-directory-with-8-million-files-but-not-with-ls/) for a potential speed-up using C. I've run into problems doing lists on 100s of millions of files, and solved the problem using the method described in the link.

Comment: How do you define huge? A few hundred? Thousand? One hundred million?

Comment: @senshin: The bottleneck can be an the OS/Python interface.  Even in 3.4 all the directory entries are read in at once, which can make reading large directories slow or impossible.  See [Issue 11406](http://bugs.python.org/issue11406) for details.

Answer (score 3):

If the issue is that the directory simply has [too many files in it](http://bugs.python.org/issue11406), this will hopefully be solved in Python 3.5.

Until then, you may want to check out [scandir](https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir).

Comment: Yes, [os.scandir()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.scandir) was added to Python 3.5 and returns a generator that yields simple [os.DirEntry](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.DirEntry) objects containing file path and other file attributes.

Answer (score 2):

You should make use of the `in` keyword to test if a directory name matches a keyword.

```
for _, dirnames, _ in os.walk(START_FOLDER): 
    for name in dirnames:
        if any((k in name.lower() for k in FOLDER_WITH_KEYWORDS_DELETION_EXCEPTION_LIST)):
            ignoreList.append(name)
```

If your `ignoreList` is too big, you may want to think about creating an `acceptedList` and using that instead.

Comment: Now it requires python 3, which should be mentioned since OP didn't tag either 2.x or 3.x.

Comment: @GVH what isn't p3k compatible?

Comment: You should never have to use `True` and `False` in a ternary `if` expression. `True if x in y else False` is the same as simply `x in y`. Second, you've still mixed up the OP's test. OP checks whether any keyword is a substring of the name; not whether the name is a substring of any keyword.

Comment: And yet you still didn't correct the direction of the substring test.

Comment: This will save a little time, but won't help at all if the OP has too many directory entries (and the OP could save the same time by adding a `break` after the `append`).