# python get files recursively

Tags: python

I have a folder structure:

I am using os.walk(path) to get all the files from the "test" folder. I would like to all files except the folder "B" and the files inside it.

test (root-folder)

- t1.txt
- t2.txt

1. A

- f.txt

2. B

- f1.txt

3. C

- f4.txt

```
list1 = ['A', 'C']
result = [os.path.join(dp, f) for dp, dn, filenames in os.walk(path) for f in filenames if os.path.splitext(f)[1] == '.txt']
  for items in result:
     for fname in list1:
       if fname in items.lower():
         result.remove(items)

print(result)
```

I tried it, but it takes only the A and C. Not the files in main folder? Can you help? Where am i wrong?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not an expert at list comprehensions (and I will not pretend that I understand yours), but are you checking for ONLY zip-files at the end when you write `os.path.splitext(f)[1] == '.zip'`? It confuses me, since you have no .zip files in the provided example.

Comment: ah sry, let me change it.

Comment: An easier way to get all files recursively is `glob.glob("**/*")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - walk through a huge set of files but in a more efficient manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718179/python-walk-through-a-huge-set-of-files-but-in-a-more-efficient-manner)

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar : thanks, already tried that part and isn't working as expected.

Comment: @PUser what do you mean by path 'B' is dynamic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible solution is to use glob library:

```
import glob

dir_to_exclude = ['B', 'C']

files = glob.glob('**/*.txt', recursive=True)
files_paths = [_ for _ in files if _.split("\\")[0] not in dir_to_exclude]
files_names = [_.split("\\")[-1] for _ in files if _.split("\\")[0] not in dir_to_exclude]

print(f'List of file names with path: {files_paths}')
print(f'List of file names: {files_names}')
```

Comment: Thank. But the path 'B' (is dynamic). Thats why I cannot use it exactly.

Comment: Thank @Grey. worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work

```py
file_paths = []
forbidden_path = GetForbiddenPath()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(root, name)
        if forbidden_path in file_path:
            if os.path.splitext(file_path)[1] == '.txt':
                file_paths += [file_path]
```

Comment: Thank. But the path 'B' (is dynamic). Thats why I cannot use it exactly.

Comment: just make it dynamic? edited. how about this?